# Pandas colnames not found after grouping and aggregating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my data

```
threats = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-08-18/threats.csv', index_col = 0)
```

And here is my code -

```
df = (threats
.query('threatened>0')
.groupby(['continent', 'threat_type'])
.agg({'threatened':'size'}))
```

However `df.columns`  only `Index(['threatened'], dtype='object')` is the result. That is, only the threatened column is displaying not the columns I have actually grouped by i.e continent and threat_type although present in my data frame.

I would like to perform operation on the continent column of my data frame, but it is not displaying as one of the columns. For eg - `continents = df.continent.unique()`. This command gives me a key error of `continent` not found.

Comment: Did you `reset_index` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried this `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` . Doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't do `drop=True`. It will drop those groupby columns that are in index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After groupby...pandas put the groupby columns in the index. Always reset index after doing groupby in pandas and don't do `drop=True`.

After your code.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

And then you will get required columns.